# Gulp watch task throws EBUSY error while mongod process is running

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gulp, watch

I've spend hours trying to solve this myself while searching for similar problems but without any luck so I concluded that the only thing to do was to post a question in here.

I'm developing a backend for a web app where I use MongoDB for data persistence. I use Gulp and have a watch task that watches for changes in js-files. I'm also using browsersync, so whenever i run gulp in the terminal, the web app will be loaded automatically in the browser. Before I run gulp, I start the mongod process using the "mongod --dbpath" command. So far so good, and no problems.

But when I then run gulp, the watch task throws an EBUSY error:

**Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, scandir 'H:\source\app\server\db\mongoDbDir\mongod.lock'**

This is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('watch:server', ['server:start'], function () {
var config = require('../../../config')().watch.server;

console.log('CALLING GULP WATCH');
gulp.watch(config.scripts, ['server:restart']); // throws the error
```

});

The config.scripts just refers to js-files in some folders (including the mongo db path directory even though there's no js files here). The other tasks being run are:

```
    // run server
gulp.task('server:start', ['build:server'], function () {
    var config = require('../../../config')().entrypoint.server;
    server.listen({path: config.source, execArgv: ['--debug=5859']});
});
```

and

```
    // restart server if entrypoint changed
gulp.task('server:restart', ['typescript:server'], function () {
    server.restart();
});
```

The "server" used here is a Node Js module from the gulp-develop-server module. And the error I get is shown on this picture:

[Error shown in WebStorm Ide's terminal when running gulp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR3Dm.png)

I did find this: 
[Grunt Serve watch throws EBUSY warning over mongod.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679526/grunt-serve-watch-throws-ebusy-warning-over-mongod-lock)

This was for Grunt, though, but I tried to ignore the path to my MongoDB in the watch task and it didn't help.

I'm really stuck here and I can't use the web app as long as this error is there, because the development server will not respond to anything.

Can anyone help me with this maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one of my teammates actually solved this. The error was that I had my db path inside my source code, which gulp was watching. So moving the mongo db to the default C:\data\db and then running just "mongod" without the dbpath was the solution!